# Delete Git project in Sap Web ide Full Stack

Tags: git, sapui5, sap-web-ide

I use `SapWEB IDE Full Stack for SapUI5 Project` and I want to `commit` my work but unfortunately I have to `pull` before and I don't want because my version is stable and I want to `push` It, but I can't Push without `Pull and merge before`.
My idea is to `delete` the `GIt project` and to set up a new from scratch.

I knew that i can `remove the .git directory` but In Sap WebIde there isn't accessible folder .git.

How can I do that . And Is it the best solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web IDE is pretty clamped down and there are no CLI commands to execute. You can however use cloud platform git on your own machine like you would github or bitbucket or a service like that, and in that case the git command line is yours to use however you want. What I've done in the past is clone the repo from cloud platform and force push changes from my laptop. Be careful of the email address you use, depending on the cloud platform setup this might need to be your corporate account or something. It's not exactly what you asked for but it's often enough to fix a bad situation.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to look for solution in your case...

First of all just remember you need to commit localy.

```
git add .; git commit -m "Your commit"
```

If you delete the .git directory you will lose all it's commits history and that could works sometime for recovering notes and stuff, instead doing that I recomend you to delete the remote with:

```
git remote rm <xx OLD REMOTE xx>
```

and then create a new repo and add it's remote with:

```
git remote add <xx NEW REMOTE xxx>
```

if you don't have idea of what is the remote you can always list the remote with:

```
git remote -v
```

....

Howeve, you can always create a new branch for your stuff and then use it and switch to master when it makes sense.

Creating a new branch just type:

```
git branch <BRANCH NAME>
```

And then checkout to branch...

```
git checkout <BRANCH NAME>
```

You will be working smoothly without losing your stuff.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Excuse but you don't understand the question, I am speakong about Sap WebIde and we don't have access to  CLI

Comment: Sorry, I get that now. Apologize... however I saw that you can use the GUI and create a new branch, have you tried it?

Comment: Ok itried it but How can I do to transform this new branch as the master of project

Comment: You would need a CLI to set your new branch as the master branch (since you don't want to merge the branches).

Answer (score 0):

You can still commit locally and then pull and fix the issues because you will need to do it anyway at some point and it is better to do it earlier than later.

Another advice is to cover at least your stuff with unit tests which will indicate later if the merge influenced on your code or not.

In general, it feels for me that you are not working in a *separate branch*. In the case when you have your own branch for the specific task you are not facing the situation that somebody did some commits that you did not want. Moreover, in this case you will be able to try to merge the master branch into your branch and see if you can resolve the conflicts or/and fix the issues what master branch has and only after that `commit and push`.